# Define Rails Model Persistent Attributes in Model File

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently played with [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) in Rails using [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/). I like the ability to define attributes for models within the model file (as opposed to in migrations):

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :birthday, :type => Date
end
```

For projects that **cannot** use a schema-less database, does a similar feature exist? Any gems or plugins that generate schemas from a similar syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both MongoMapper and Mongoid took their ideas about this from [Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/getting-started)
 which also support those SQL database.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Exactly what I needed! Appreciate the quick answer!